# How to have a jQuery Modal window open on html form submission

Tags: jquery, html, forms, modal-dialog

I am using a simple html form to submit a product from my website to my remotely hosted Mal's e-commerce shopping cart. 
I need to have a modal window (containing an iframe) open when the form is submitted. I don't have access to server-side programing for the shopping cart, so is there a way to launch the jQuery modal window using an onclick html event attribute?

Right now, the onclick attribute at the bottom of the form opens a js browser alert...basically I need to replace this js alert with my jQuery Modal Dialog window.

Can anybody help?

Here is my form as is:

```
<form action="http://ww7.aitsafe.com/cf/add.cfm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="96309001">
<input type="hidden" name="nocart"> 
<input type="hidden" name="producturl" value="http://www.fruitfulfarm.net/cart_2.html">
<input type="hidden" name="product" value="Test Product">
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="49.99">
<input type="hidden" name="return" 
value="www.fruitfulfarm.net/cart_2.html">
<input class="rounded" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add To Cart"
onclick="alert('Order has been added to your cart\n\nThis page will refresh');"
onkeypress="alert('Order has been added to your cart\n\nThis page will refresh');">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI For the Dialog?

Comment: What about using onsubmit for the form tag?

Answer (score 3):

Use `onsubmit`

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return myModal(this)">
    <!-- more inputs -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function myModal(f)
{
    var form=f,
        modal=$('<div/>', {
            'id':'alert',
            'html':'<iframe src="url"></iframe>'
        })
       .dialog({
           'title':'Iframe in a modal window',
           'modal':true,
           'width':350,
           'height':'auto',
           'buttons': {
               'OK': function() { 
                   $(this).dialog( "close" ); 
                   // do something, maybe call form.submit();
                }
            }
    });
    return false;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/HeyrG/)

Comment: how do I reference the JS function you gave to the onsubmit tag? do I   simply upload the JS in a file, and put the URL to it in the tag?

Comment: You can keep the function in the head `tag` wrapped with `script` tags.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand... I have the HTML form in a snippet, and I don't know what to do with the JS, and how to reference the function to the onsubmit tag.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: The `js` code/function should goes in to `<head><script>function myModal(f){,..}</script></head>` and the put the `form` in the `body`.

Comment: Also you can keep your <script>function myModal(f){...}</script> in the body, maybe above the `<form></form>`.

Comment: I did both of your suggestions with wrapping the JS code in script tags and placing it in the head tag, and also wrapped in script tags, placed it above the html form in the body.  I don't get any modal window to come up after hitting the submit button, I just land on the form action URL. Why is this?

Comment: Where have you put the onsubmit, itshould go in to the form, like `<form action="..." onsubmit="return myModal(this)">`

Comment: <form method="post" action="http://ww7.aitsafe.com/cf/add.cfm" onsubmit="return myModal(this)">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="96309001">
<input type="hidden" name="nocart"> 
<input type="hidden" name="producturl" value="http://www.fruitfulfarm.net/cart_2.html">
<input type="hidden" name="product" value="Apple Wreath">
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="49.99">
<input type="hidden" name="return" 
value="www.fruitfulfarm.net/cart_2.html">
<input class="rounded" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add To Cart">
</form>

Comment: I have the JS code wrapped in script tags, just above the form. But I have also tried putting the JS code in the head as well, but I've had no success.

Comment: @AaronH, did you add the `jQuery` and `jQuery-ui` scripts in the head ?

Comment: Which jQuery scripts do I need for this? Thanks for your continued help on this!

Comment: [Check this](http://jsbin.com/oxilam/1/edit) and see the `HTML` panel, all `scripts` and `stylesheet` for the `ui`.